AdvancedMarkerElement: making drag behaviour more like legacy Marker
With the legacy Marker, when dragging a marker there is a nice little crosshair to give the impression of a precise positioning movement, and this crosshair disappears automatically at the end of the drag... see this example.
Relevant code:
async function initMap() {
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    const { Marker } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

    const myLatLng = {
    lat: -34.397,
    lng: 150.644
  };

    const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 8
  });
  
  const marker = new Marker({
    map,
    position: myLatLng,
    draggable: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    const position = marker.getPosition();
    alert('dragend at ' + position);
  });
}

initMap();

In case it doesn't show the same in every browser, this is what I see when dragging the marker:

Compare this to the new AdvancedMarkerElement... no crosshair, and instead some bounding box that IMHO is unnecessary and looks plain ugly... see this example.
Not only that, but the bounding box remains after the end of the drag... at the very least how so we ensure that focus is removed from the marker at the end of the drag?
Relevant code:
async function initMap() {
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

    const myLatLng = {
    lat: -34.397,
    lng: 150.644
  };

    const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 8,
    mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID", // Map ID is required for advanced markers.
  });
  
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: myLatLng,
    gmpDraggable: true
  });

  marker.addListener('dragend', function(event) {
    const position = marker.position;
    alert(`dragend at (${position.lat}, ${position.lng})`);
  });
}

initMap();

In case it doesn't show the same in every browser, this is what I see when dragging the marker:

This gives the appearance of a development version of the feature, rather than a finished version... just looks awful?

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182937497 marked as fixed twice but apparently it's still not fixed.

@MrUpsidown OK it's promising to know that this horrible bounding box isn't necessarily a design feature, but less promising that the issue has been unsolved for 3 years... unless perhaps it is a design feature in Google's eyes and really is here to stay.  Would still like to know about how to get the cross-hair on dragging... if this AdvancedMarkerElement is meant to be better in every respect than a Marker then surely it shouldn't be losing useful touches like this?

These borders were added as an accessibility feature, as you can read in this article. You could disable focus for all elements with a rule like :focus { outline: none !important; } but that is probably not a good idea. What is really confusing is that Google said that the focus outline should appear when an element is focused by keyboard interaction, not when dragging a marker with the mouse. Feels like nobody knows now what they implemented and why and what's really the expected behavior.

Thanks for the further insight.  For something that's been in development for over three years, and with Marker now deprecated, you'd think they'd have ironed these useability issues out by now?
